# SEO How frequently one can change the title of website

Tags: seo

How frequently one can change title of the website? would that make any difference in website rank for search keywords if one change the title of website once and then reverse it back to previous ones.

Actually I have changed the title of website from "A | B | C" to "A | B | C | X | Y | Z". I have severely loose the rank for keywords A, B, C. Website was on front page for these keywords but now its on fourth page in Google. then again I reverse the Keywords back to "A | B | C" but keywords positioning are still on fourth page. It has been more then 3 weeks. and Google Crawler has visited my website for almost 3 times in this time but website position for these keywords are still same? while title has been updated in Google.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more possibility. You say you had three keywords in your title and than added three more. Maybe Google saw that as keyword stuffing and gave you a little slap. That would explain the drop in the rank, even though you have reverted to your previous keywords the rank will have to grow normally like in the beginning. That is the beauty of Google slap, you get down fast, but go back up very slow!

but I agree with Pierre, you probably did something else. maybe not on site, maybe just added some links from bad neighborhoods or something similar. stuffing keyword in the title is not a grounds for Google slap alone, so there has to be something else, think it through!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the title will affect your ranking, but I doubt that is caused the drop alone. Did you change anything else?

You can change your title frequently, but each time the spiders visit your site, your ranking will be updated.

Try to invest in your link popularity and your content. You can only get better ranking on more and more keywords if you do things right (not tricking the spiders).

Comment: I have not changed any thing. I means from last 6 months my site for certain keywords(20) was on front page. while 4 weeks ago, i introduce 3 more keywords in my title of home page and my rank for all keywords(20) dropped. I immediately reverse my changes in title but in vain. This behaviour is beyond my understanding. I place this  Question, may be someone else faced the same problem? I have observed that crawler visit my site on every weekend. because i have set the visit frequency weekly. Yes I am working on the Link popularity as well.

Comment: Any change will affect your ranking, but being on fourth page for 3 words seems a bit strange. Did the spider visited your site since you removed those three words ?

Comment: yes it did. and now it has been 3 weeks since i reverted the changes and spider has visited the site twice. Spider is visiting site on every Saturday.